# How do I make deeply namespaced generators work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example generator:

```
module MyPlugin
  module Generators
    module SomeNamespace
      class ThingsGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
        # stuff
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As expected `rails g` outputs this:

```
MyPlugin:
  my_plugin:some_namespace:things
```

So that should work, right? Wrong:

```
> rails g my_plugin:some_namespace:things
Could not find generator my_plugin:some_namespace:things
```

So, what's going on? Rails can see the generator, it's totally testable too via `Rails::Generators::TestCase`.

Any thoughts? I can always make a `my_plugin:some_namespace_things` but it just looks uglier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is what it was. For some reason, rails uses different methods for listing and executing generators. My problem was with filenames.

So if your generator looks like this:

`my_plugin:some_namespace:things`

your file structure should look like this:

`lib/generators/my_plugin/some_namespace/things_generator.rb`

Super simple.